# how to insert textField with tableView into PDF file

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I'm using code to create a PDF File. Works.

But: I want my whole UITableView(I need to scroll) in my PDF File and not just the part of the view which is currently displayed on screen.
laso i need to add three textField to the same file PDF
this must be take all the content of view (three textField and the tableView with all cell) because this is an invoice
Is there a way to achieve this?
i use the following code

```
- (void)saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename;

{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];


    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];

}
```

but the problem it take as image to the view and the remaining cells for tableView didn't include PDF file

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.tablview.bounds, nil);try this.

Comment: not working also take a screen shot for the existing cells

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *viewToRender = self.tableView;
CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToRender.bounds.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//  KEY: need to translate the context down to the current visible portion of the tablview
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -contentOffset.y);

[viewToRender.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


try this
```

Comment: remove the above method completely and use this code? or remove the first portion only; and what about the image where i can use this variable